# Why does the Aburame clan cover their eyes?

Tags: naruto

The explanation in [Naruto Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Aburame_Clan) was not sufficient so I decided to go through the trouble to ask here. :)

Given that the defining traits of an Aburame is to wear something to cover their eyes and to dignify their whole body, why is it that they cover their eyes in the first place? Whilst, the other noble clans like Uchiha and Hyuga never covers theirs? Does covering their eyes boost their power? Or does it have to do with the insects getting on their eyes? Or might it be that their eyes are not presentable or not to be shown to the public?

Any philosophies that might shed light to the importance of protecting the Aburame clan's mysterious eyes?

Answer (score 8):

They **do not** cover their eyes. They use sunglasses/dim glasses for protection.

Since they are known for having the characteristics of insects, we can assume that they have crepuscular vision and some have nocturnal traits - meaning that they are most active in twilight/low light/night. Their eyes are highly adapted on low light.

Therefore, using their naked eyes are like humans using Night Vision goggles. Just imagine the amount of light they will receive during daylight.

Source: [Insect Vision](http://cronodon.com/BioTech/Insect_Vision.html)

Comment: The scientific explanation on this one is pretty much on the spot! But wouldn't it be more of quality and improve their ability to sense threat without their glasses on since their eyes probably can see more because it has more or improved lenses?

Comment: Yes, given that they have improved senses. But as you can see, there must be something special on their glasses. It can be an adaptive glasses too.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that it's simply to look cool.

It's also entirely possible to just be a visual cue to help viewers to immediately identify a member of the Aburame clan. You can almost always tell what clan the character is in based on how they look.

- Uchiha have black hair, dark or blue clothes, and the Sharingan,
- the Hyuga clan have black hair, white or light colored clothes, and the Byakugan.
- the Akimichi clan are usually rotund, have markings on their cheeks, have the kanji for 'food' (食, shoku) on their armor, and have some shade of brown or red for their hair.

My best guess is that the Aburame clan is shown with some form of shades, a heavy coat or jacket, and bugs that fly from their sleeves, which is why you rarely see their eyes.

[image: Shino Aburame, side view with eyes clearly shown behind his glasses. Regular black pupils, and regular white sclera (The rest of the eye other than the iris and pupil) in typical anime fashion.]

Answer (score -2):

For me personally, I think it's because they have bug eyes.

Check out season 3 episode 47, 7 min 35 sec into the episode. You'll see what I'm talking about looking at Shino's eyes.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE. There's [an existing answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/14919/2516) explaining why its insect eyes might cause the problem. Comparing to that, this answer seems too short in detail: why do they have to cover their eyes if they have bug eyes? Consider [edit]ing the answer to expand and improve it. Lastly, you might also be interested in taking a quick [tour] to get familiar with how this site works. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I think it's so that insects don't crawl into their eyes, Maybe most abarume clan people don't totally *love* bugs in their eyes and wear goggles, but the more passive ones wear shades just to fit in.